# Fastest way to create multiple list items (around 2000 items) into a list using C#/CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

Somebody please suggest me the **fastest way to add multiple items into a SharePoint list**.

My current c#/csom code is taking too much time in populating the list. And I have to do this activity every day :(

Currently, I am creating the list items one by one. Is there any way to do it in batch-wise?

Below is my code.

```
foreach (var value in valueCollection)
{
   ListItemCreationInformation iteminfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
   ListItem newListItem= ActionTasksList.AddItem(iteminfo);
   newListItem["column1"] = value.value1;
   newListItem["column2"] = value.value2;
   newListItem["column3"] = value.value3;
   newListItem["column4"] = value.value4;
   newListItem.Update();
   rootcontext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: Please share your code, then how do you have your data to put it into SharePoint list ? add more information to your question.

Comment: Are the item values always different or the same? If the latter maybe you can create list template.

Comment: You could always look at using [Asynchronous Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) or [C#'s Await functionality](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/). These'll use more threads and speed up your code by a few factors. 5 threads will speed up your code approximately 5 times.

Comment: @MarekSarad The values will get updated every day. I think in that case I can't use the list template.

Comment: @KGlasier Is there anything which I can use to add a ListItemCollection directly into List rather than adding each Item one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve the performance of your code by not calling `rootcontext.ExecuteQuery();` after adding every item. Depending of the size of your columns, you can call `ExecuteQuery` after every 30 or 50 items or so (the best way to find the optimal number would be if you make a couple of tests and see when the size of the request is too big). 
I usually do it this way, please find your updated code below:

```
int cnt = 0;
foreach (var value in valueCollection)
{
   ListItemCreationInformation iteminfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
   ListItem newListItem= ActionTasksList.AddItem(iteminfo);
   newListItem["column1"] = value.value1;
   newListItem["column2"] = value.value2;
   newListItem["column3"] = value.value3;
   newListItem["column4"] = value.value4;
   newListItem.Update();
   if (++cnt % 30 == 0)
   {
    rootcontext.ExecuteQuery();
   }   
}
rootcontext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: I've tried this approach, but not seeing much difference in performance. Taking around 40-45 minutes to add 2000 list items.

Comment: can you try to increase the number of items (30 in my example) to 100 or maybe 200?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below PowerShell code which is adding multiple items to the Sharepoint list - the number of items to add is configurable.

```
CLS
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
#Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
#Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$fileName = "Adding_Multiple_Items_Report"
$enddate = (Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMddhhmmss")
$logFileName = $fileName +"_"+ $enddate+"_Log.txt"   
$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value  
$directoryPath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path 

$directoryPathForLog=$directoryPath+"\"+"LogFiles"
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForLog))  
        {  
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForLog

        }   

$logPath = $directoryPathForLog + "\" + $logFileName  
$isLogFileCreated = $False 

#DLL location
$directoryPathForDLL=$directoryPath+"\"+"Dependency Files"
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForDLL))  
        {  
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForDLL

        } 

#DLL location
$clientDLL=$directoryPathForDLL+"\"+"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
$clientDLLRuntime=$directoryPathForDLL+"\"+"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"

Add-Type -Path $clientDLL
Add-Type -Path $clientDLLRuntime


function Write-Log([string]$logMsg)  
{   
    if(!$isLogFileCreated){   
        Write-Host "Creating Log File..."   
        if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPath))  
        {  
            Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        }   
        else   
        {   
            $script:isLogFileCreated = $True   
            Write-Host "Log File ($logFileName) Created..."   
            [string]$logMessage = [System.String]::Format("[$(Get-Date)] - {0}", $logMsg)   
            Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value $logMessage   
        }   
    }   
    else   
    {   
        [string]$logMessage = [System.String]::Format("[$(Get-Date)] - {0}", $logMsg)   
        Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value $logMessage   
    }   
} 

#variables region.
$siteURL="https://globalsharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite/"
$spUserName="yourSPOAccount@globalsharepoint.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "YourPassWord"
$spListName="Test List"
$numberOfItemsToCreate="5001"
#variables region end.

$securePassword= $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

#Setup the Context

try
{
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($spUserName, $securePassword)


#Get the list
$spList = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($spListName)
$ctx.Load($spList)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Loop thru to create the list items.
for($i=1; $i -le $numberOfItemsToCreate; $i++)
{
  $listItemCreationInformationInSPOnline = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
  $newListItemInSPOnline = $spList.AddItem($listItemCreationInformationInSPOnline)
  $newListItemInSPOnline["Title"] = "CustomItemNumberAddedThruCode_1_$($i)"
  $newListItemInSPOnline["CustomItemNumber"] = $i;
  $newListItemInSPOnline.Update()


  write-host "Item created in SP Online list: $spListName  CustomItemNumberAddedThruCode_$($i)"
}
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

}
catch 
{

    $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message +"in adding mulitple items in SP Online list using CSOM PowerShell script";
    Write-Host $errorMessage -BackgroundColor Red
    Write-Log $errorMessage 
}

Write-Host "####################################################################"  -ForegroundColor Green 
Write-Host "The script execution has been completed!" -ForegroundColor Green 
Write-Host "###################################################################"
```

Reference URL:

[Create multiple items in a list using PowerShell CSOM](https://global-sharepoint.com/powershell/create-multiple-items-in-sharepoint-online-list-using-powershell-csom/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute ClientContext.ExecuteQuery() onetime after for loop like this, this will submit all new created items into SharePoint list in One Time:

```
            List oList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MainList");
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);

                oListItem["Title"] = "My New Item " + i.ToString();
                oListItem.Update();
            }
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```